# Not able to scroll through flatList in react-native-svg

Tags: react-native, react-native-svg

I have a created a rectangle using react-native-svg and added a flatList inside that rectangle, Its showing all the items but I am not able to scroll throught the list. Please check if I am missing something or what?

```
<Svg style={styles.container}>
    <Defs>
        <LinearGradient id="grad" x1="0" y1="0" x2="1" y2="0.6">
            <Stop offset="0" stopColor="red" stopOpacity="1" />
            <Stop offset="1" stopColor="yellow" stopOpacity="1" />
        </LinearGradient>
    </Defs>
    <Rect x="0" y="0" width="100%" height="100%" fill="url(#grad)"></Rect>
    <FlatList
        contentContainerStyle={styles.flatListContainer}
        data={DATA}
        renderItem={this.renderData}
        horizontal
        showsHorizontalScrollIndicator={false}
        keyExtractor={(item) => item.id}
    />
    </ScrollView>
</Svg>
```

I tried adding ScrollView to FlatList also, but it didn't work.

```
<ScrollView>
    <FlatList .../>
</ScrollView>
```

(Trying out react-native-svg for first time)

Answer (score 0):

Add style with

```
{flex : 1}
```

in FlatList Component.

Comment: It didn't work.. list is showing even scroll indicator is visible if I set showsHorizontalScrollIndicator={true} but unable to scroll through the list.